# CSS3 different background color element coming from top

Tags: html, css

Right now I'm doing this to animate an element background color.

```
<style>
.container{
    padding: 30px;
}
.element {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #c00;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.element div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0c0;
    transition:top 0.5s ease;
}
.element:hover div {
    top: 0px;
    transition:top 0.5s ease;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">some text<div>some text</div></div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Lxrou4/).

Is there any "cleaner" way to have the same animation? Right now I'm duplicating my content to achieve this.

Comment: use pseudo elements - would make this much cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo elements for this, and **not** have to duplicate any content:

It's basically moving one pseudo from above the element, and bringing it down over the element on the hover

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
div:after {
  top: -100%;
  background: green;
}
div:hover:before {
  top: 100%;
}
div:hover:after {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Text? Why would you ever want text?</div>
```

---

If you want the text to 'move' as well, you can do something similar:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:20px;
  width:300px;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
div:after {
  top: -100%;
  background: green;
}
div:hover:before {
  top: 100%;
}
div:hover:after {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Text? Why would you ever want text?"></div>
```

**Note:** [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) suggests it is widely supported (bit I admit only tested in latest chrome, so only going by this for cross browser). However, This may affect SEO, and so I would be reluctant to use this in production.

---

If you just wanted the 'upper' element to flow over the top of the text (instead of 'lower' text scrolling as well), You could do:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
div:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  top: -100%;
  background: green;
}
div:hover:before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="The text I always wanted">The text I always wanted</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `background-position`

Set a `linear-gradient` to 50% of each of the background colors and set the background size to be 200% of the actual div.

Then animate it and move the background 100% up. Like this:

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #c00;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c00 50%, #0c0 50%);
}
.element:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
  transition: background-position 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">some text</div>
</div>
```

This cuts out the need for any duplicate content in either the css or the html.

Comment: its  little different

Comment: What about the content animation? if you look at my demo, you will see that the content is moving together with the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pseudo element :before and get the text with attribute like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" data-text="some text">some text</div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.container{
    padding: 30px;
}
.element {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #c00;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.element:before {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0c0;
    transition:top 0.5s ease;
}
.element:hover:before {
    top: 0px;
    transition:top 0.5s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/g3Lxrou4/3/

Comment: This raises a problem: because the website is multi language, that what you suggest cannot be achieved.

Comment: Oh well, maybe an js script gonna help to for content so

Comment: I just edit, get the content on markup with attribute and not duplicate the div to

Answer (score 0):

just similar to [jbutler483](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876988/3556874), but using just a single pseudo class. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/g3Lxrou4/5/)**

```css
.container {
  padding: 30px;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #c00;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.element:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  content: 'some text';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0c0;
  transition: top 0.5s ease;
}
.element:hover:after {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">some text</div>
```

Comment: You don't need that container div (it's redundant in this example). :P

Comment: @jbutler483 .no my code is dirty anyways.. I assumed it will be there.. but i will edit